# Did the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) wash his hands before eating?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

Did the Prophet wash his hand before eating?

Did he use soap or something similar, or plain water?

*Answers based of sahih hadth would be appreciated.*

Comment: [Soap's possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap#Early_history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *1st hadith*:

This hadith can be found in Sunan Abu Dawud, under the chapter "Washing the hands before eating (12)":

> Narrated Salman al-Farsi:
>   I read in the Torah that the blessing of food consists in ablution before it. So I mentioned it to the Prophet (ﷺ). He said: The blessing of food consists in ablution before it and ablution after it.
>   Sufyan disapproved of performing ablution before taking food.

[Sunan Abu Dawud - sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/26)

**Abu Dawud and Albani said this hadith is weak.**

### *2nd Hadith*:

This hadith can be found in Sunan Ibn Majah, under the Chapters on Food:

> Kathir bin Sulaim narrated that he heard Anas bin Malik say:
>   "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: ‘Whoever would like Allah to increase the goodness of his house, should perform ablution (wash hands) when his breakfast is brought to him and when it is taken away.’"

[Sunan Ibn Majjah - sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/urn/1333850).

**Also classified as a weak hadith, according to Darussalam**

---

Although these hadiths are weak, it is OK to follow them since they are considered [Fada'el al A'amal (فضائل الأعمال)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/what-does-fazail-e-amaal-mean).

Also, as there was no mention of soap, you are free to use whichever material helps clean your hands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.. I've been waiting for so long.

Comment: if a hadith is weak it does'nt mean that it is wrong, and islam prioritises hygiene which conforms to scientifical studies classifying the said hadith as true automatically.