# What does Faza'il-e-A'maal (فضائل الاعمال) mean?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

In the [answer #13271](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/13271/885) of the question "[Did the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) wash his hands before eating?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/did-the-prophet-muhammad-peace-be-upon-him-wash-his-hands-before-eating)", the user mentions that the two quoted hadiths are considered part of Faza'il-e-A'maal  (فضائل الاعمال).

What exactly does that mean? And what are the conditions that, if met, make a hadith be one of Faza'il-e-A'mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Sharia, we are not allowed to use weak hadiths to derive Fiqh and Ahkahm rules.**

Sahih(Authentic) and Good(Hasan) hadiths are the only hadiths which can be used for that. Thus, any Hadith:

- Weak (not fabricated nor really weak).
- has contents which don't state something is halal or haram.
- People do "r assume that the hadith is a sunnah of the prophet.
- There exists another verse or/and hadith which confirms this Hadith (example below).
- Only enjoin good and forbid bad deeds (i.e: Be kind to parents, remembering allah when entering markets, etc..)

Such Hadiths fall under the criteria of Faza'il-e-A'maal (فضائل الاعمال).

---

**For example,** the hadith below is an example of weak hadith. However, There are verses in the Quran that confrims this hadith.

> Ibn 'Abbas (May Allah be pleased with them) said:
>   The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "If anyone constantly seeks pardon (from Allah), Allah will appoint for him a way out of every distress and a relief from every anxiety, and will provide sustenance for him from where he expects not."

[[Abu Dawud - Sunnah.com]](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/20/5)

The veses that backs this hadith:

http://quran.com/71/9-12, this http://quran.com/11/3, and [this](http://quran.com/search?q=%D9%88%D9%85%D9%86%20%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D9%8A%D8%AC%D8%B9%D9%84%20%D9%84%D9%87)

---

**Note:** There is a book called Faza'il-e-A'maal. Check Ansari's answer for more information.

***Please*** don't confuse between these two. One is a **book** and the other one is a **concept**

Answer (score 2):

Fada'il al-A`mal literally means "The Virtues of Deeds." In this case, it is referring to a book compiled nearly 100 years ago by a Deobandi scholar (Muhammad Zakariyya Kandahlwi) which is very popular among Deobandi and Tablighi Jama`at circles as an easy-to-understand-and-implement book for lay Muslims. The book has attracted significant criticism for its inclusion of extremely weak and fabricated stories.